# Capturing Traffic on Local Machine With Multiple NICs On Linux

Tags: routing

So I have a virtual CentOS machine with multiple virtual NICs. I'm working on a project where we need to stand up an echo server on each of the NICs, listening on a particular port. Both the client, and the servers, and therefore the traffic, are local to the machine. I'm observing a strange behavior in the traffic flow when I start a client and connect to a local IP/port. Here's what I'm seeing: 
1. The client connects to the Server IP successfully, and sends data out successfully. 2. The server receives the data successfully.

So far, so good. The other part of the project is to collect the network stats from the system files, specifically, from /proc/net/dev.

I run a cat command in a loop on /proc/net/dev, and grep for the adapter that I'm targeting in my client application. I see no data in the "received bytes", and "transmit bytes" columns. However, I do see traffic on the loopback adapter ("lo").

So the question is, why am I not seeing any traffic on the targeted adapter in the /proc/net/dev file while the server on the said adapter does receive packets from the client?

Secondly, is this a routing table issue, and if so, can we do something about it so we can collect the metrics from the /proc/net/dev file for that particular adapter?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, all traffic is local to the same system; even if you're specifically targeting IP addresses bound to NICs, the system will still treat this traffic as loopback; it will not actually flow through the NIC itself.

Comment: Hi Massimo, thanks for your response. Is there a way I can force the traffic to go over the specific NIC, rather than over the default loopback adapter? Do I need to tinker with the routing tables? And if so, how do I accomplish that?

Comment: I fear this is not possible. When the kernel has to handle local network traffic (defined as traffic between two IP addresses it owns), it simply will not involve the actual hardware in handling it. Your best bet would be to set up another VM to act as a client, then you will be able to examine the actual traffic flow between the two.